# Can't load One To Many navigation property in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

My question may be a littler more specific and I'm just learning EF Core. I have two classes. tblBuilding and tblBuildingHour. Simple classes. Don't mind the naming convention of the tables. It's a legacy database. It works fine if I remove the navigation properties. What am I missing? Is there something I need to do for the Castle proxy configuration? Is it the composite keys? Is it the lazy loading of the navigation property? I'm stumped.

```
public class tblBuilding {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<tblBuildingHour> BuildingHours {get;set;}
}

public class tblBuildingHour {
    public int BuildingID {get;set;}
    public DateTime BuildingHourDate { get;set; }
    public DateTime StartTime {get;set;}
    public DateTime EndTime {get;set;
    public virtual Building Building {get;set;}
}
```

There's lazy loading of the entities in my db context.

```
services.AddDbContext<EMSDataContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection(EmsDevDb).Value)
    .UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory));
```

In the dbContext I added the one to many relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblBuilding>()
    .HasMany(b => b.BuildingHours)
    .WithOne(r => r.Building)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.BuildingID);
```

The only odd thing in this tblBuildingHour table is that it has a composite keys so I don't know if that's what's messing it up.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblBuildingHour>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.BuildingID, c.BuildingHourDate });
```

I wondered if the lazyloading was affecting it so I tried this to no avail.

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

Comment: Did you try eager loading? Context.tblBuildings.Include(_ => _.BuildingHours). Also you can specify the database table name with modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().ToTable(“table-nem-string); so you don’t need to use these namings in your c# class.

Comment: I did try the include after adding the one to many. but got the same result. It looks like i have a record or records, but it doesn't resolve when i try to access any of the properties. Thanks for the suggestion on table naming.

Comment: I am thinking that the problem is with your composite key (as you mentioned). Try addig a new column (Id) which will replace the BuildingID in the composite key and you can keep the buildingId for the foreign key. Other thing you can try is add new { BuildingID, BuildingHourDate } as the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core creates the relationships provided you create your entity classes **correctly**. After looking closer at my classes, I removed the fluent api relationship, changed my entity classes to have `List` instead of `ICollection` properties, removed `.Include` from my repo queries, and it worked like a charm. Eager loading wasn't the solution. Surprisingly enough, it wasn't even the composite keys. EF Core managed to create the relationships correctly after I removed mine.

Addendum: to be clear, removing .Include is not part of the fix, that was only for lazy loading.

**REMOVED**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<tblBuilding>()
    .HasMany(b => b.BuildingHours)
    .WithOne(r => r.Building)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.BuildingID);
```

**UPDATED**

```cs
[Table("tblBuilding")]
public class EMSBuilding
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual List<EMSBuildingHour> Hours { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[Table("tblBuildingHours")]
public class EMSBuildingHour
{
    [Column("BuildingHoursDate")]
    public DateTime BuildingHourDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }

    public int BuildingID { get; set; }
    public virtual EMSBuilding Building { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<EMSBuildingHour>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.BuildingID, c.BuildingHourDate });
```

Comment: That's weird. It doesn't change anything essentially. The mapping follows EF's mapping conventions, so EF will ad the same mapping internally. `ICollection` vs `List` has no bearing on the issue. The original code should work. Did you really show all code related to these two classes?

Comment: The only thing I left out was all of the properties for the sake of saving space. And I agree, that's why I created the post in the first place. It didn't make sense. In retrospect, I may have fooled myself by not eager loading the navigation property with .Include and assuming it wasn't working.